# Modeling Entities with SQLite EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I have class Teacher and SubjectTeacherDetail. I modeling like this :

```
  private static void SubjectTeacherDetailModel(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         modelBuilder.Entity<SubjectTeacherDetail>().HasKey(s => new { s.Id });
         modelBuilder.Entity<SubjectTeacherDetail>().HasRequired(r => r.Teacher).WithMany(m => m.SubjectTeacherDetail).HasForeignKey(k => k.TeacherId);
    }
```

I add entity like this:

```
 var st = DataProvider.GetEntity<Teacher>().FirstOrDefault();
                var subjectdetail = new SubjectTeacherDetail()
                {
                    Teacher = st
                };
                DataProvider.AddEntity(subjectdetail);
                DataProvider.SaveChanges();
```

When I get Teacher from DB, it returns an empty collection of SubjectTeacherDetail. Where I made mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved issue, but something is strange. It works when I get all  SubjectTeacherDetail from DB like this:

```
 Teachers = new ObservableCollection<Teacher>(DataProvider.GetEntity<Teacher>());
        var detail = DataProvider.GetEntity<SubjectTeacherDetail>().ToList();
```

Can anyone explain why it works like this?